# Cannot find module 'compare-func' Cordova Android

Tags: android-studio, cordova, npm, cordova-android

I've got a Cordova v10.0.0 project using Cordova Android v9.0.0, I'm experiencing a problem when trying to build the project for Android, I'm getting the following error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/MYUSER/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Failed to instantiate ProjectBuilder builder: Error: Cannot find module 'compare-func'
```

I've tried removing my Node Modules folder, running a `cordova clean android` and re-installing with `npm install`. Not quite sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: yes i am facing same issue with android but ios is working fine. Please let me know if you got some solution.

Comment: What worked for me was to run `cordova platform rm android` and then re-install it with `cordova platform add android`

Comment: I had npm installed cordova-android 8.1.0, ran cordova prepare, then npm installed a different cordova-android, then running cordova build android gave this error. indeed removing and re-adding the android platform and rebuilding worked for me.

Answer (score 27):

I faced the same issue and I installed compare-func npm package ([Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compare-func)) (`npm i compare-func`) and it worked for me.

Comment: I tend to remove the platform in instances like this, always seems to work lol.